# Number of Permutations without the the "diagonal terms"

Tags: probability, permutations

If I have a set of n numbers (we can say n is 5, to create a concrete example), then there are n! (5!) different ways of arranging these numbers.

How many of these don't use the "diagonal terms" - i.e, the first term isn't a 1, the second term isn't a 2, and the nth term isn't an n.

My thinking was that at first, you have n!.

Step 1) you remove all the ones with a 1 in the first place:
    n! - (n-1)!

Step 2) you remove all of the twos in the second place:
    n! - ( (n-1)! - (n-2)! )

We subtracted out (n-2)! because some of those twos were already removed by (Step 1)

This doesn't work though - for 5 terms, it yields 47 when it should yield 44
Thoughts?

Comment: It may also help you investigate this if you know that what you call "diagonal terms" are usually called "fixed points".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the classical problem of counting [Derangements.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)  The problem occurs under many other names, such as *Rencontres*. We want to count the number, often called $D_n$, of permutations of $\{1, 2,\dots,n\}$ with no fixed points. We have`
$$D_5=(5!)\left(1-\frac{1}{1!} +\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}\right).$$

The derivation of the general formula is a quick Inclusion/Exclusion argument. The article linked to is brief, but does the job.

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble phrasing it in google and couldn't find that article!